# How many positive integer $m$ satisfy $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{p}$, for integers $n$ and $p$ distinct from $m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

I was looking at a past paper and I stumbled upon this question, and I was very confused.

Here’s the question:

> A number is the “reciprocal” of another number if their product is equal to 1. Suppose the sum of a reciprocal of a positive integer $m$ and the reciprocal of 2 is equal to the sum of the reciprocals of two integers that are different from $m$. How many possible $m$ would satisfy this condition?

I made this formula, I’m not sure if this is the correct way to do it ($n$ and $p$ are the two other positive integers besides $m$, also unknown)
$$\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{p},\ m > 0,\ n \neq m,\ p \neq m $$

I’ve tried isolating $m$, but I don’t know how to continue from there.
$$m=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{2}}$$

In addition, I don’t really feel like this is the right approach, since this equation can’t really tell me how many different results there are going to be. I would really appreciate some help!

EDIT: This is supposed to be a test question, so methods like running through each possible possibility is not really plausible.

Comment: Run through possible values for $n$ and $p$, and see if any of them work.

Comment: Hint: Show that if $  n \leq p$, then $ n  < 4$. Thus, we only need to check $n = 3$.

Comment: It might be useful to multiply the original equation [The first displayed equation in your question] by the product $2mnp$ and arrive at an equation on $m,n,p$ with no fractions left. It may or may not be helpful, just a suggestion.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Why? Where did the 4 and 3 come from?

Comment: Suppose the opposite, that is, $n\ge4$ and $p>4$. How big can the RHS be? Can it be as big as $1\over2$? Can it be _greater than_ $1\over2$?

Comment: You only say "integers" $n$ and $p$, not "positive integers"?

Comment: No, I did say $n$ and $p$ were positive integers.